# Selecting blank and non-blank cells using google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I new to scripting and have a range of data 3 columns wide which I would like to add borders to based on column 1.  I need to check to see if the cell (cells) immediately below is a blank or non-blank cell.  If the cell (or cells) below are blank I want include those cells when setting the border but having some issues.  Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried something like this but no luck

```
var range = sheet.getRange(row,1, totalrows,3);
  var data = range.getValues();

  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != "" &&
      data[i+1][0] != "") 
    {
      sheet.getRange(i,1,1,3).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,false);}
  }
```

sheet, rows and totalrows have been defined earlier

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this might me one way:

```
var counter = 1;
for (var i = 1, length = data.length; i <= length; i++)
{
  if (i == length || data[i][0])
  {
    sheet.getRange(i + row - counter, 1, counter, 3).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,false);
    counter = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    counter++;
  }
}
```